# inno setup overlapping text labels error

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I use "Inno download plugin" in my inno installer, The text labels in the idp download page get overlap on another (see image below), I guess it something to do with "Tab Order"?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the most recent version of IDP with Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u). Tab order is the order in which the controls get focus when you press TAB key, so it should be unrelated. I can check the IDP plugin source, but I think that this downloading page is rendered by the plugin itself (and if I'm correct, then I can't imagine what would break the look this way). Can you reproduce it with a demo script ? If so, which version of IDP and IS do you use ? If not, can you narrow this problem to a short script where we could reproduce this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved, i re-installed the programs and it's fine now

Comment: If that's the case, I recommend deleting your post as it will be of no use to future users. As such, I have voted to close it.